# "Read only file system" for non-root disk

Tags: hard-drive, files, disk

I have a hard drive mounted at `/media/jack/Disky` that I use to store movies, music, etc. It is full, but when I went to delete some files in Nautilus it displayed an error message: "Read only file system". How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add the output of `mount | grep '/media/jack/Disky'` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned the filesystem type, but it looks like it got mounted (read `man mount`) read-only. Type `mount | grep Disky` to be sure.

To mount it read-write (or get an informative (!) error message:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/jack/Disky
```

If it's an `NTFS` filesystem, last used on Windows, you may have to take it back to Windows, mount the disk, and unmount it through Windows.

Comment: When I tried to delete a directory it said it was deleting three times the actual amount of files within. I looked at Disks and here's what it said about the space left: 1.0 TB — 1.4 TB free (1844301742.2% full). Very strange glitch. I tried deleting a directory with terminal and the thing turned into gibberish and was making popcorn noises.

Comment: If you have a second question, ask another Question! AskUbuntu is a Q&A site, not a conversation site. How would future you search for the 2nd question or its answer?