# How can I gain write permissions on an NTFS hard drive?

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, ntfs

I have an NTFS hard drive that I've been using for a few years to store movies and music (`/dev/sdb1`).

Up until this year, I was using Windows. After installing Ubuntu, I realized the drive was full, but I can't remove any files from it, even from nautilus.

How can I gain permission to delete files from this drive?

Comment: Please take a look at the answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037128/read-only-file-system-for-non-root-disk#comment1688160_1037128 and try if this helps.

Comment: lWindows 8 or 10? If so may be hibernated. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation